# Perl: How to access values of identical siblings

Tags: xml, perl

I would like to access the value of each cell of nodelists I retrieved with:

```
$xc->registerNs('ns', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet');
foreach my $row ($xc->findnodes('/ns:Workbook/ns:Worksheet/ns:Table/ns:Row'))
```

they have the following format:

```
<Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">sbdsvrwm832</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">3.0.6</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">5.0999999999999996</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"/></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NA</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NA</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">N/A in SHV3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">YES</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"/></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">YES</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">2013-09-20</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NO</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"/></Cell>
   </Row><Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">sbtorsvr832</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">4.0.1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">3.011111111</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"/></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ORI</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NA</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">N/A in SHV3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">YES</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"/></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">YES</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">2013-07-18</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NO</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"/></Cell>
   </Row>...
...
```

Note that the Cell/Data elements do **NOT** have names or IDs that can be used with XPath expressions (they are mostly identical elements, some values may be null or contain whitespaces). Is there a way I can access data of an arbitrary cell for each of such row by index? Thanks in advance.

Alex

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean there, as you already have the row in your each collection. There's an XPath function called position() that might come in handy though.

Comment: I want to get access to data in arbitrary cell (column) of each row. the your suggestion is interesting. would you please give a example on how to process this $row using the position function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath expression you're looking for is (relative to a `Row` element)...

```
"Cell[position()=$i]/Data"
```

... where `$i` corresponds to an index (1-based!) of the element you're looking for.

If you need to retrieve all the items having the same position for *all* the rows, just prepend this expression with `//Row/` (assuming you're querying from the root element). For example:

```
my @nodesOfColumn2 = $dom->findnodes('//Row/Cell[position()=2]/Data');
print $_->to_literal, "\n" for @nodesOfColumn2;
### prints... 
### 3.0.6
### 4.0.1
```